# Python insert xml/string data into PostgreSql database

Tags: python, sql, xml, psycopg2

```
import psycopg2
myConnection = psycopg2.connect( host='192.168.103.124', user='dev', password='abc123', dbname='dev')
cursor = myConnection.cursor()
teststr='<test>123456</test>'
sql="insert into nlp_train_data(context_xml) VALUES ({})".format(teststr)
cursor.execute(sql)
myConnection.commit()
```

This is what I get:

```
ProgrammingError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-190-1560207a8c5d> in <module>()
      2 teststr='<test>123456</test>'
      3 sql="insert into nlp_train_data(context_xml) VALUES ({})".format(teststr)
----> 4 cursor.execute(sql)
      5 myConnection.commit()
      6 #except:

ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "<"
LINE 1: insert into nlp_train_data(context_xml) VALUES (<test>123456...
```

I very much appreciate if anyone could possibly help. Thanks.

Comment: Please don't use Python's string formatting to build your query. [Pass your values as parameters instead](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries). `cursor.execute("insert into nlp_train_data(context_xml) VALUES (%s)", (teststr,))`

Comment: @shmee it worked, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

While string formatting in python, the passed value ignores the single quotes (').
So you can do this **('%s')** instead of **(%s)**

```
sql="insert into nlp_train_data(context_xml) VALUES ('%s')" % (teststr,)
```

Comment: To quote the [docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#the-problem-with-the-query-parameters): Never, **never**, **NEVER** use Python string concatenation (`+`) or string parameters interpolation (`%`) to pass variables to a SQL query string. Not even at gunpoint.

Comment: @shmee: agreed just referred to the doc, if you use the sql string inside the execute statement, better follow the above guideline, else only for string format you can use the answer as stated.

Comment: Thank you, but I got "InternalError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block" if trying to insert with the sql you provided.

Comment: Can you try this sql=("insert into nlp_train_data(context_xml) VALUES ('%s')", (teststr,))
This error basically comes when the an errored transaction was not rollbacked successfully.